# Android FrameLayout hosting a viewPager consumes all available space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm trying to create a "tutorial" (like this one from AirBnb app) with different images and text (both hosted inside a Fragment), and managed by a (Fragment)ViewPager inside a FrameLayout.
As the exampe above I want also to display two buttons at the bottom of the screen, my problem is that the FrameLayout which contains the ViewPager concumes all available space, thus hiding the LinearLayout wich contains the buttons.

It's a weird situation since the layouts are very simple, I tried different ways but nothing solves my problem. I checked that only the root elements of the layouts were in fill_parent mode, and checked also that all other layouts avoid to grow exceeding their required space to display their info.

Here are some snippets, xml layouts for activity and for each child fragment displayed by the FragmentViewPager:

**activity-tutorial.xml (This one I've tried with LinearLayout as a root element instead of RelativeLayout, but nothing changes)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pager_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/buttons_bottom_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_below="@id/pager_framelayout">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Sign UP" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_tutorial_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/tutorial_screen_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tutorial_screen_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the java code for instantiate the fragment and populate the views with info:

**TutorialScreenFragment.java**

```
{ //...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Identify and set fields!
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.subfragment_tutorial_screen, container, false);
    image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_screen_image);
    title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_screen_title);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Populate fields with info!
    if (TutorialActivity.class.isInstance(getActivity())) {
        title.setText(titleResId);
        // Call Glide to load image
        Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageResId)
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
        .into(image);
    }
}
/...
}
```

Everything works fine, also the dots wich show the current page, but the buttons aren't displayed at all. This is my app result:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the behaviour of your layout. Firstly, align your `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the parent. And then place your `FrameLayout` above `LinearLayout`. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pager_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_bottom_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/buttons_bottom_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Sign UP" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've had to use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", but it works fine! Awesome! Thanks! Do you know why this happens?Are there any online resources which explain this situation? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, sure, it should be `android:layout_alightParentBottom="true"`, my mistake. Your `ViewPager` have been fullscreen, so bottom buttons were below `ViewPager`, it means they were out of screen.